# Javascript does not call GET methods more than once due to Caching issues in browser. ResponseCaching does not fix issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I made an application that uses Javascript (Vue.Js) to call my API and update lists on the page when I add a new Object to that list (in this case a list of users).

I made the mistake of only testing on Edge, where it updated itself perfectly if I made a get-call after I had updated the list. However, every other browser seems to cache it somehow, and does not call `GET api/users` more than once (noticed that by adding breakpoints).

In the past ASP.NET version adding `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]` most likely would have solved the Issue, but that does not work in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

I read up and found that `ResponseCaching` Is supposed to replace it. So I added it to my project and followed the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response) on how to implement it, but no luck.

To Startup.cs (as well as all required code to add the interface to my scope) I add:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.CacheProfiles.Add("Default",
            new CacheProfile()
            {
                Duration = 60
            });
        options.CacheProfiles.Add("Never",
            new CacheProfile()
            {
                Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None,
                NoStore = true
            });
    });
}
```

Then to the top of each controller in my API I add:

```
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Never")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
```

This does not solve my issues, instead it seems to clear the accesstoken I use for my users so I can't keep users signed in anymore. Is this not the solution I need to fix my problem? Am I implementing it in the wrong way? Not sure where to go from here.

Here is what My Ajax calls in JS looks like:

```
addAdmin: function () {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api/admins',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(self.adminCreate),
                success: function (response) {
                    self.getAdmins(false);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error: ' + textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
//gets called on Start as well as after each AddAdmin call. 
getAdmins: function (toggle) {
            var self = this;
            if (!self.adminOpen || !toggle) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'api/admins',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (toggle) {
                            self.toggleAdminOpen();
                        }
                        self.admins = response;
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Error: ' + textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (self.adminOpen) {
                self.toggleAdminOpen();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser is not making the call again, then try adding this JavaScript (before anything else):

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false}});
```

The effect of this is that jQuery will add the current time as a URL parameter in every AJAX call. It will be ignored by the server, but it makes the URL "different" so that the browser sees every call as unique and thus unable to use its own cache.

Comment: Do I just add this at the very top of my .js file?